# in-file selection of a number and only keeping those lines starting with that number in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have  files with the  format given below. Please note that the entries are space seperated.

```
16402       8    3858    3877    3098    3099
3858  -9.0743538e+01   1.5161710e+02  -5.4964638e+00
3244  -9.7903877e+01   1.8551400e-13   1.0194137e+01
3877  -9.2467590e+01   1.5160857e+02  -5.4969416e+00
4330  -9.3877419e+01   8.8259323e+01  -5.4966841e+00
3098  -9.2476135e+01   1.5336685e+02  -5.4963140e+00
5431  -6.1601208e+01   3.3540974e+01   1.0309820e+01
3099  -9.0752136e+01   1.5337535e+02  -5.4963264e+00
3600  -6.3099121e+01   1.3944173e+02  -5.4964156e+00
5418  -6.6785469e+01   2.9993099e+01   1.0291004e+01
```

There are lines with 6 entries and there are files with 4 entries. The lines with total of 6 entries have last 4 entries as the node number and the lines with 4 entries are those node numbers with there spatial coordinates. I want to keep only those nodes in the 4 entry lines which are listed in the 6 digit lines and delete all the others so that my files would look like

```
16402       8    3858    3877    3098    3099
3858  -9.0743538e+01   1.5161710e+02  -5.4964638e+00
3877  -9.2467590e+01   1.5160857e+02  -5.4969416e+00
3098  -9.2476135e+01   1.5336685e+02  -5.4963140e+00
3099  -9.0752136e+01   1.5337535e+02  -5.4963264e+00
```

This file is already created with some data processing so keep the format is important. I have thousands of lines with 6 digits entries and 4 digit entries in a file so a general solution would be helpful for me to learn and apply to other cases too. Any suggestion with sed or awk?

thanks

Comment: Does a line with 6 columns only applies to the following lines with 4 columns until a new line with 6 columns appears?

Comment: @hek2mgl, no first there are thousands of lines with 6 entries and then come the lines with 4 entries again thousand of lines!

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Does it work with that large amount of rows with 6 fields? Does it have an acceptable performance? If performance really matters, I would code that in C and use a clever lookup technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following awk script:

```
awk 'NF==6{print;b=b" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6}NF==4{if(b ~ "\\y"$1"\\y") print}' input.txt
```

*Explanation:*

The command manages a buffer which contains all the last 4 fields of the lines with six columns. The variable is called `b`. Every time `awk` enters a line with six columns it prints that line and appends it to `b`.

If a line with 4 columns is entered `awk` checks if `b` contains the value of the first field `$1` using the function `match()`.

*Output:*

```
16402       8    3858    3877    3098    3099
3858  -9.0743538e+01   1.5161710e+02  -5.4964638e+00
3877  -9.2467590e+01   1.5160857e+02  -5.4969416e+00
3098  -9.2476135e+01   1.5336685e+02  -5.4963140e+00
3099  -9.0752136e+01   1.5337535e+02  -5.4963264e+00
```

---

Note, if it is safe that a line with 6 columns only applies to the following lines with 4 columns until a new line with 6 columns appears, the command can be changed to:

```
awk 'NF==6{print;b=b" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6}NF==4{if(b ~ "\\y"$1"\\y") print}' input.txt
```

which would perform a lot better since the maximum buffer size will be only a single line.

Comment: This could generate a lot of false positives. For example, a line whose first field is 402 would also be printed because 402 appears as part of an irrelevant field in a 6-field line.

Comment: @Wintermute Thanks! Added the `\\y` escape sequence for word boundaries.

Comment: Well, that's a bit better in principle, but you'll still match 16402 and 8. And now you only select for those first fields that appeared in the last six-field line.

Comment: If there's a four-field line whose first field is 16402 or 8, it'll be selected because you remember not only the last four fields of the six-field line but all of them. Aaand...for the last bit I was looking at your second piece of code, so that's my bad, but you'd at least have to use `b = b " " $0` to match along word boundaries later. You'd concatenate the last field of one six-field line with the first of the next otherwise.

Comment: `If there's a four-field line whose first field is 16402 or 8, it'll be selected because you remember not only the last four fields of the six-field line but all of them.` Ups,, overlooked that in the question.. let me change that :)

Comment: @Wintermute About the `\y`. It matches also the start or the end of the line. Check this: `awk '$1 ~ /\y1\y/' <<< '1'`

Comment: That is true, but if you concatenate two lines `1 2` and `3 4` to receive `1 23 4`, neither `\y2\y` nor `\y3\y` will match. That was a problem with `b = b $0` in your code at the time.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right again! However, my recent attempt fortunately doesn't have that issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would store the 4 numbers in an array, and then test that $1 occurs in the array.

```
awk '
    NF == 6 {
        delete n
        for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)
            n[$i]=1
        print
        next
    } 
    $1 in n
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 6-field lines consistently appear before the 4-field lines they select, then

```
awk 'NF == 6 { for(i = 3; i <= 6; ++i) a[$i]; print } NF == 4 && $1 in a' filename
```

will work. That is as follows:

```
NF == 6 {                         # in a six-field line:
  for(i = 3; i <= 6; ++i) a[$i]   # remember the relevant fields
  print
}
NF == 4 && $1 in a                # and subsequently select four-field lines
                                  # by them
```

Otherwise, you'll need a second pass over the file and handle the six-field lines in the first and the four-field lines in the second pass:

```
awk 'NR == FNR && NF == 6 { for(i = 3; i <= 6; ++i) a[$i]; print } FNR != NR && NF == 4 && $1 in a' filename filename
```